# AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'applymap' while applying logTransformation

Tags: python, pandas, transformation

Log Transformation of column containing values like <0, >0 using Python is giving error.
Is this the correct way..?
df["A3"].applymap(lambda x: np.log(x+1) if x>0 else -np.log(-x+1) ).hist()
plt.show()

Comment: are we supposed to guess the error? :-) My shot will be that `'Series' object has no attribute 'applymap'`. Am I right? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applymap is a dataframe level function and you are trying to apply it on a single column(which is a series), so is why it throws this error

check the original documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html)

Instead you can use 'apply' function which is for series as stated [enter link description here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply)